# In clojure, how can I select and return a subset of a collection

Tags: collections, clojure

If I have a collection like this

```
{{:A "a" :B "b"} {:A "a" :B "Goal" } {:A "a" :B "Goal"}}
```

how do I make a function so it returns only the parts where `:B "Goal"`? Meaning only:

```
{{:A "a" :B "Goal" } {:A "a" :B "Goal"}}
```

Comment: curly brackets are maps in Clojure and require an even number of members (key and value pairs) they can be of any type : keyword, string, number.. your collection above will be better represented as a vector `[,,,]` or a list`'(,,,)`

Answer (score 6):

I fixed your data to make it a vector of 3 maps.

```
(def data [{:A "a" :B "b"}
           {:A "a" :B "Goal"}
           {:A "a" :B "Goal"}])

(defn b-goal?
  [item]
  (= (:B item) "Goal") )

(filter b-goal? data) => ({:A "a", :B "Goal"} {:A "a", :B "Goal"})
```

---

Be sure also to check out:

- [The Clojure CheatSheet](http://jafingerhut.github.io/cheatsheet/clojuredocs/cheatsheet-tiptip-cdocs-summary.html)
- [Clojure for the Brave and True](https://www.braveclojure.com/)

As well as books like

- Living Clojure
- Getting Clojure